# JFlex : Reading from multiple files

Tags: flex-lexer, jflex

I recently started using JFlex and came across the need to read from multiple input files in a specific order.When it finishes the first file i want Jflex to continue with its current state and the scanner to continue from the new file.

So far everything works fine when I have only 1 input file :

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input1"));
Flexer scanner = new Flexer(br);
scanner.yylex();
br.close();
//lame attempt for second input(not working)
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input2"));
scanner.yylex();
br.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFlex doesn't appear to support `yywrap()`, which is how you do this in *lex* and *flex,* but the easy way to do this is as follows:

```
InputStream in = new SequenceInputStream(...);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
Flexer scanner = new Flexer(br);
```

where the `...` provides you several ways to specify the input files, either as an `Enumeration<? extends InputStream>` or as a pair of `InputStreams:` note that you can use the latter recursively, e.g.

```
new SequenceInputStream(s1, new SequenceInputStream(s2,s3));
```